# Lambda AWS Rekognition to DynamoDB - Error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@Kalefive/https-medium-com-kalefive-using-aws-rekognition-and-lambda-to-analyze-images-on-the-fly-61cd1adae0af) to link Rekognition results to a DynamoDB table. 
It is giving me this error:

```
{
"errorMessage": "Unable to get object metadata from S3. Check object key, region and/or access permissions.",
"errorType": "InvalidS3ObjectException",
"stackTrace": [
    "Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27)",
    "Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)",
    "Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)",
    "Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)",
    "Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
    "AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
    "/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
    "Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
    "Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)",
    "Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)"
]
}
```

The code used from GitHub is [this](https://github.com/KaleFive/Categorize).

I made sure the region-name is the same for the lambda-bucket and the table.

I am a starter in this, so any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Edit:
I made some modifications and now it is giving me this:

```
{
"errorMessage": "Requested resource not found",
"errorType": "ResourceNotFoundException",
"stackTrace": [
    "Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27)",
    "Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)",
    "Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)",
    "Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)",
    "Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
    "AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
    "/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
    "Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
    "Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)",
    "Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)"
]
```

}

Comment: Is the S3 bucket containing the object in the same region as Rekognition API endpoint that you're calling?

Comment: @jarmod Yes- the lambda, table and bucket are all us-east-1

Comment: Please test with an image whose filename is one simple word, for example faces.jpg rather than "test faces.jpg". If you upload the latter file using the S3 console then it will show up in your Lambda function with a key of test+faces.jpg (space is escaped to a plus sign) and that will not be found by Rekognition, leading to the original ResourceNotFoundException.

Comment: @jarmod I did, and I don't think this is the problem

Comment: That github project works fine here (in us-east-1). I followed the instructions in the Medium article, made sure that the IAM role for the Lambda had both AWSLambdaFullAccess and AmazonRekognitionFullAccess, modified config.js with the DynamoDB table name, deployed the code, and dropped an image into the S3 bucket. That triggered the Lambda function which made the necessary Rekognition calls and persisted the results into DynamoDB correctly. I *did* hit the ResourceNotFoundException initially but that was because my filename was "test faces.jpg", as previously mentioned. So it does work.

Comment: @jarmod can you please tell me which line you modified in the code? what do you mean by modified config.js with the DynamoDB table name? You really can save my life with your answer

Comment: @jarmod I get you!! OMG I ma so null! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you're seeing `ResourceNotFoundException` suggests a couple of potential causes:

- the Lambda function could not find the DynamoDB table: make sure that you modified config,js to include the name of the DynamoDB table correctly, by setting `config.dynamo.tableName = '<your table>'`
- Rekognition could not read the image from S3: make sure that the image filename is of the form `faces.jpg` rather than `test faces.jpg` (which gets escaped to `test+faces.jpg`)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of reasons why this could be happening:

1) The resource definitely does not exist. Triple-check Bucket name, DynamoDB Table name, regions, etc.

2) It's very likely that your function lacks permissions. Check the IAM Role that your Lambda function is using and attach the right policies to it. On this case, your function needs access to S3, DynamoDB and Rekognition. Make sure all of these policies are attached to the IAM role.

Comment: Thank you for your answer- I checked all this, I even made the bucket public and it is still giving me the same error-

Comment: Have you configured your SDK to point to the specific region? Something like AWS.config.update({region: 'my-region'})

Comment: I did- still not - sorry

Comment: If I were you I'd try to isolate the problem by reducing your code to only connect to a DynamoDB table. If you still keep on getting the resourceNotFoundException than it's easier to track.

Comment: This is not working as I am using a ready made json code (I know nothing about nodejs). I am trying this using python now, which I am familiar with.  I just posted this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54824911/sed-recognition-response-to-dynamodb-table-using-lambda-python Can you help?