# Why can't my Lambda function find my DynamoDB table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I'm new to AWS and I am struggling with it a little.

I have been following an Amazon tutorial on how to

1. Create a permission and role
2. create a Lambda function
3. create an API to talk to the Lambda function
4. create a DynamoDB table that the Lambda function will change

This is the tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway-tutorial.html

My problem is that I follow the instructions but when it comes to testing the API's POST method in the API Gateway console I get these confusing messages in response:

Request: /dynamodbmanager

Status: 200

Latency: 1719 ms

Response Body

```
{
    "errorType": "ResourceNotFoundException",
    "errorMessage": "Requested resource not found",
    "trace": [
        "ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found",
        "    at deserializeAws_json1_0ResourceNotFoundExceptionResponse (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_0.js:3090:23)",
        "    at deserializeAws_json1_0PutItemCommandError (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_0.js:2088:25)",
        "    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)",
        "    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-serde/dist-cjs/deserializerMiddleware.js:7:24",
        "    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb/dist-cjs/baseCommand/DynamoDBDocumentClientCommand.js:18:34",
        "    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist-cjs/middleware.js:13:20",
        "    at async StandardRetryStrategy.retry (/var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/StandardRetryStrategy.js:51:46)",
        "    at async /var/runtime/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist-cjs/loggerMiddleware.js:6:22",
        "    at async Runtime.handler (file:///var/task/index.mjs:33:16)"
    ]
}
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong. It seems as if the table doesn't exist (even though I have created it).

Comment: I agree it seems like the table specified doesn't exist. You need to show your code though otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: check this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54816799/lambda-aws-rekognition-to-dynamodb-error)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your API Gateway resource tree?

Comment: If you are building the Lambda function using NODE JS or Python as described in that example (not sure if the logic even works), you should at very least test the Lambda function from the AWS Lambda Console. See if the issue is in your code or somehow issue with how you use API Gateway.

Comment: Code is in the link the community member posted.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to create an AWS Lambda function. The ways described in that doc (Node or Python) are a few supported ways.

If you want to learn how to build an AWS Lambda function that successfully interacts with an Amazon DynamoDB table, then take a look at this step by step document. It builds a Lambda function using the [Java Lambda Runtime API](https://javadoc.io/static/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-core/1.2.1/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/RequestHandler.html).

The use case is the AWS Lambda function that detects personal protective equipment (PPE) in images located in an Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket. After you execute the Lambda function, it detects PPE information in the image using the Amazon Rekognition service and creates a record in an Amazon DynamoDB table.

If you follow this step by step dev doc, you will not get that  ResourceNotFoundException.

See: [Creating an AWS Lambda function that detects images with Personal Protective Equipment](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_lambda_ppe)

How do I know this works? It's tested a lot and I just re-tested. The Lambda function works:

[image]

and data is written to the table.

[image]